# Selection Sort Comparisons

Tags: c++

I have to keep track of all comparisons in this selection sort, but when I do only 1 is returned for the value out of a list of 1000.  I am not sure I implemented it correctly but I am sure I placed the comparison count correctly/. Typically a selection sort has a fixed amount of key comparisons but our instructor has forbidden the use of formulas to track them. I am curious why this output keeps returning:

```
comp = 1
swap = 1 

template <class elemType>
void selectionSort(elemType list[], int length)
{
    int loc, minIndex;
    int first; 
    int last, second;
    int swaps =0;
    int comp = 0;

    minIndex = first;
    for (loc = 0; loc < length; loc++)
    {
        comp+=1; 

        for(loc = first +1; loc<=last; loc++)
        {
            comp+=1;
            if(list[loc]<list[minIndex])
                minIndex=loc;
            comp+=1;
        }
        elemType temp;
        temp= list[first];
        list[first]= list[second];
        list[second] = temp;


        swaps+=1;
    }

    //  comp = (length *(length-1)/2);

    cout<<"swaps= "<<swaps<<endl;
    cout<<"comps= "<<comp<< endl;
}
```

Any thoughts are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your sorting itself is not working. You need to properly initialize `last`, `first` and `second` variables (specially the `last`) and then move(increment) them.

**Since your `last` variable is defaulted with `0`**, its not performing the iterations because of `loc<=last` condition in the second for loop as you have desired. I think you need to initialize it as :

```
 last = length-1;
```

**There is one more issue:** In both the loops, you are using the same index variable i.e. `loc`. I think you need to use two different variables.

```
for (loc = 0; loc < length; loc++)
{
  comp+=1; 
   for(loc = first +1; loc<=last; loc++)
   {
```

**Once you fix the logic so that it performs the full sorting, you will get the right count.**

Comment: This fixed the comparison(to a degree, the number is quite low, but I get a number) but swaps are still not working.

Comment: @Craig: Good to know. Please revisit the logical errors in the sorting.  Please let me know, if you need help in fixing.